# Wait for termination - Install4j

Tags: install4j

We are using Install4j to build installers for 2 applications (Let's say A and B). Application **A** is installed first and **B** is installed next if the user has selected to install **B** when installing **A**. For **B** to install, **A** must be already installed and if **A** is not installed, then the installer for **B** is not running. There is a step in installer **A** to open the installer **B**. This step is of type **Run executable or batch file**.

In this step, when I check `Wait for termination`, opening of the Installer **B** fails with **A should be already installed to install B**. (But at this moment **A** is already installed). The same can be seen when I directly run Installer for **B** without installing **A**.

But when I uncheck `Wait for termination` the Installer for **B** runs as expected.

So, my question is what this `Wait for termination` really does?

Comment: It waits until the process terminates and keeps installer A alive. How do you check in installer B if A is already installed?